# visual studio task failed intellicode custom completions user credentials invalid

Tags: visual-studio, intellicode

My company provided me with Visual Studio 2019. It has been working, (as much as this dinosaur can be said to be working,) and it has been showing my initials on the top-right corner, meaning that I am in some way "signed in".

Recently it started teasing me about Visual Studio 2022. Contacting the IT department to discuss what to do would be too much of a hassle, so I just proceeded to download Visual Studio 2022, I installed it side by side with 2019, and it has been working more or less exactly the same way. My initials still appear on the top right corner.

However, every once in a while, it shows me this popup:

[image]

It says:

> Task failed: IntelliCode Custom Completions
>
> Your task failed with the message:
>
> Visual Studio user credentials invalid.
>
> Click here to sign in.

And it has an "Always ignore" link.

If I "click here" (I do not know what they mean by "here", so I click on the word "here",) the popup disappears and there is no trace of it that I can find. So, in order to see it again I have to wait until a random point in time when it will decide on its own to re-appear. Other than that, everything still seems to be working fine. I am not prevented from getting any work done.

I am using ReSharper, so I have the luxury of not knowing (and not particularly caring to know) what "IntelliCode Custom Completions" are, and whether they are currently working or not.

Does anyone have the faintest clue as to what might be causing this and how I might be able to make it stop?

Comment: Same problem, same lack of solutions.

Comment: VS 2019 is just broken.  I did exactly what you did.  Except VS 2022 caused issues with my older projects so I stopped using it.  I did notice that it somehow added the "hot" update button to 2019 and it actually works.  UNLESS...the hot update button was always there but I never noticed it!  Also, all my hot keys got screwed and I can't get them back to the default settings.  Many others cannot either.

Comment: @JoeSchmucker yes, all of VisualStudio is broken.  I think it has been broken since the late nineties.  And there seems to be no cure.  I mean, the cure would be to have this dinosaur thrown away and rewritten from scratch, and apparently that is what they are attempting to do with this little abomination known as "VSCode", but it is a very long way from home.

Comment: Visual Studio 2022 has this nonsense too. I always have to fight with work/home credentials which are identical yet Microsoft refuses to unify them (7 years now). And then this thing comes up. Which I won't mess with as I know it'll break my sign in again.

Comment: Anyone found a solution to this bug yet?

Comment: @falowil I have not found a solution, but I have not seen this happening in the last couple of months, so maybe it is gone.  Maybe, it fixed itself. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rtX79lg2354

Comment: It definitely didn't fix itself, I see this once a day or so in VS 2019. I'm not signed in and I don't want to and it usually happens after a while (hours?) I start working on some project. (My VS has the license key applied.)

Answer (score 0):

In VS 2022 it does show up under the notifications window in the button left hand corner of the IDE, after clicking on the notification icon.  You can then click on the hyperlink "IntelliCode Custom Completions" in the notification header:

[![How to find the error][1]][1]

As far what credential it wants, IDK